# Installing complex software at customer site

Tags: fixed-price

To ship a project you always need to install something on customer's PC/server. There are 2 options: make it yourself or write an instruction for them. It's not that important if the setup is small. But now I'm facing a setup which took around 2 working days on my PC because of compilation time and resolving issues both. I'm using those frameworks for the first time (will definetely be somewhat faster the second time). It's a fixed price project.

Should I add this as additional cost? I always have feeling that I should be well-familiar with the software on which I'm basing my solution (I usually do not, in fact), so presuming this I consider installation an easy process that is not paid separately.

Furthermore, the customer is tempted to make it themselves to get experience for further deployment. But they will definetely run into problems and most probably it will spend both my/their time. I'm also not very tempted to provide educational services.

Answer (score 1):

Are you being paid to deploy the project as well? It sounds like you are, but check your contract.

If it is going to take lots of time to deploy something for a customer, you need to be the expert in learning what common pitfalls there are, and how to remedy them *before* you go onsite.

Fixed-price projects are just that - fixed price. They're nice for the customer because they know *exactly* how much to expect to pay. Do not charge more without discussing it with them first, and they agree and understand *why* you need to charge more. Be prepared for angry customers if it is your first install. My recommendation is *just do the work*, and learn for next time.